# How to troubleshoot "Pragma: no-cache" with Concrete5 on Debain?

Tags: php, linux, apache, caching

## Setup

- Debian GNU/Linux 7.6 (wheezy) will full access to Apache and virtual
  host files.
- Concrete5 CMS: http://www.concrete5.org/

---

## Problem

Our website is sending `Pragma: no-cache` in headers which is stopping a number of optimisations from working - including the CloudFlare service: https://www.cloudflare.com/

---

## Solutions which didn't work

When researching, we either didn't understand the answers or they seemed to be for specific use cases (like Oracle or php frameworks we're not using) but we did try the following:

**1. Force caching via the site's `.htaccess`:**

```
<FilesMatch "\.(ico|jpeg|png|gif|js|css)$">
   Header unset Cache-Control
   Header unset Pragma
</FilesMatch>
```

**2. Force caching via Concrete5's header.php file**

```
    header("Cache-Control: max-age=2592000"); //30days (60sec * 60min * 24hours * 30days)
```

**3. Search site's root for `no-cache` using grep**

```
    $ grep -r "no-cache" * .
    backup/databasebackup.php:header('Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate');
    concrete/core/controllers/single_pages/login.php: header("Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate");
    concrete/core/controllers/single_pages/login.php: header("Pragma: no-cache");
    concrete/js/tiny_mce/plugins/spellchecker/rpc.php:header("Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate");
    concrete/js/tiny_mce/plugins/spellchecker/rpc.php: header("Pragma: no-cache");
    concrete/libraries/3rdparty/securimage/securimage.php: header('Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate');
    concrete/libraries/3rdparty/securimage/securimage.php: header("Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate");
    concrete/libraries/3rdparty/securimage/securimage.php: header("Pragma: no-cache");
```

But after looking at the files/scripts Concrete5 is setting `no-cache` on (login, database backups, text editor configs etc), we kind of understand why - plus these seem to be for specific files, not the entire site right?

**4. Make a blank php file, request it and check the header**

The blank file was served with caching on so we suspect that php is the culprit - but have no idea how to isolate the cause sorry.

---

## Question

How do we troubleshoot and fix this issue?

---

## Skill level

We do front-end design and understand the basics on how to setup and serve a CMS but don't have much experience with server configuration or troubleshooting cache issues.

We have command line access to the server and pretty much have full access to Debian, Apache, and the site's install.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Cheers

Ben

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally got to the bottom of this, some of the Concrete5 Blocks on pages are stopping the pages from being cached.

If we turn on "Force full page caching" then we see some weird behaviour because the functionality is frozen by the cache, so we've had to turn it off.

Essentially, we can't cache the site fully because of the functionality in blocks on the page. We can only use APC caching.

Answer (score 1):

### Update

To add max-age in a PHP script:

```
header("Cache-Control: max-age=xxxx");
```

Where `xxxx` is the number of seconds to cache, zero for no cache.

**OR**

If you configure by Content-Type (MIME Type)

```
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
```

---

Header Set Cache-Control "max-age=0, no-store"

**to configure cache by Content-Type (MIME Type):**
In .htaccess ot httpd.conf

```
ExpiresByType text/html "access plus 30 day"
ExpiresByType text/css "access plus 30 day"
ExpiresByType text/javascript "access plus 30 day"
ExpiresByType image/gif "access plus 1 year"
ExpiresByType image/jpg "access plus 1 year"
ExpiresByType image/png "access plus 1 year"
```

If these methods are not working you need to majke sure the modules are loaded.

You need access to httpd.conf

```
LoadModule expires_module     libexec/mod_expires.so
LoadModule headers_module     libexec/mod_headers.so

AddModule mod_expires.c
AddModule mod_headers.c
...
AddModule mod_gzip.c
```

Note that the load order is important in Apache/1.3x, mod_gzip must load last, after all other modules.

For Apache/2.0:

```
LoadModule expires_module modules/mod_expires.so
LoadModule headers_module modules/mod_headers.so
LoadModule deflate_module modules/mod_deflate.so
```

**end of Update**

---

You should add the same cache based on MIME Type as well as (or rather than) file extension.

The cache should be max-age.

The W3C says max-age takes precedence over all other cache headers.

To troubleshoot you are doing well already if you are not getting "Internal Server Error 500"

In FireFox or Chrome

- Right Click page
- Select Inspect Element
- Go to the "Network Tab"
- Change Type from "All" to "HTML"
- Click on the HTML page in the list

You should be able to see exactly what is in the HTTP Response Header.

**FireFox**

[image]

**Chrome**

[image]

Comment: Thanks heaps, sorry didn't understand the first part about MIME Types and max-age - do I just make it ```header("Cache-Control: max-age");```. I did as you suggested in Firefox and don't see any internal server errors - I see a 404 for a Google Tags manager script but that's because nothing is published to the GT container yet.

Comment: Thanks heaps but if a blank php or html file is served independently of concrete5, the header for that file has the correct caching - so does this mean that it's not an Apache issue? We'd already tried adding ```header("Cache-Control: max-age=2592000")``` to concrete5's header.php file as well.

Comment: I do not believe there is any way to override the `header()`.  What I typically see is two conflicting max-age in the header. Are there `includes` in these PHP files where the `header()` does not work?

Comment: Send me a link where I can look at the headers myself.

Comment: Find the configuration item: getCollectionFullPageCachingLifetimeValue and Look at `concretex.x.x.x/concrete/src/Cache/Page/PageCache.php`, this is where concrete messes with the headers.   function getCacheHeaders(ConcretePage $c)  In this script after the first line add a line $lifetime=86400;